# Time out while importing a repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to import a repository in Visual Studio Team Services.

The repository that I'm trying to import is a really huge one, and after some time I get the following error:

> Oops! Your import of  repository failed due to The operation has timed out.

Is there a way to increase the timeout, or does anyone know another way to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import option is just for convenience. There's nothing stopping you from cloning the repo, adding a new remote, and pushing it to VSTS.

Comment: Just be sure to clone using `--mirror` and turn off work item linking in the target repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a repo > 5.2 GB on a private git server. 
I suspect the mirror cloning failed because of an expired certificate of our git server (we had no reason to update the certificate as it was private).

I our case we ended up pushing to a private gitlab repo, then import via the Azure web import form pointing to the new gitlab repo. That worked.